# Application of Derivative

Tags: calculus

Imagine a vertical line representing the lamppost, a point moving away from the base of this line representing the skateboarder, and a line from the top of the lamppost to the skateboarder representing the light ray. The shadow of the skateboarder is the line from the skateboarder perpendicular to the lamppost, intersecting the light ray.

Comment: Cool story. What is your question, though?